# Gmaps.js Route with Distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, maps, gmaps.js

I'm using [Gmaps.js api](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) in a little project I'm building.

Basically to replicate Google Maps functionality I'm looking to get the route & distance from one address to another (can just be input/form fields).
I notice [this demo](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/travel_route.html), but it requires clicking on the map, and also doesn't show the total distance or drive time?

Any opinions on best way of parsing 2 addresses from a form, then calculating route and drive time using the gmaps.js api?

Comment: Have you tried anything you can show us?

Comment: That's a pretty neat api - did you try clicking the big button on the bottom of the page that said "documentation"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Breaking this into parts you need to:

1. Search your form entered addresses and geocode them using the geocoding API.
2. Use the results from the geocoding to calculate the route.
3. Pull required data from the route and plot/display

For Geocoding see this example: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html

```
GMaps.geocode({
  address: $('#Start').val(),
  callback: function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      var latlng1 = results[0].geometry.location;
    }
  }
}); //Repeat for destination / end point
```

Now you have your lat/long points.

You can then take a few approaches to route, but just drawing it can be done like this example: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/routes.html

```
map.drawRoute({
  origin: [latlng1.lat(), latlng1.lng()],
  destination: [latlng2.lat(), latlng2.lng()],
  travelMode: 'driving',
  strokeColor: '#131540',
  strokeOpacity: 0.6,
  strokeWeight: 6
});
```

If you call `getRoutes` instead of `drawRoute` you should get back a `DirectionsResult` object: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsResults . The `TransitDetails` object contains information on the travel time to the end location in the form of arrival time. Each `leg` will also contain a duration and distance which you can add up looping through them and access something like:

```
foreach($directions->routes[0]->legs as $leg) {
    $time+=$leg.duration.value
    $distance+=$leg.distance.value
}
```

**Update:**

Was playing with the API - and excuse the nested callbacks - but here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/82Dp2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var latlng1;
    var latlng2;

    GMaps.geocode({
        address: $('#Start').val(),
        callback: function (results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                latlng1 = results[0].geometry.location;
                GMaps.geocode({
                    address: $('#End').val(),
                    callback: function (results, status) {
                        if (status == 'OK') {
                            latlng2 = results[0].geometry.location;
                            map = new GMaps({
                                div: '#map',
                                lat: latlng1.lat(),
                                lng: latlng1.lng(),
                                zoom: 12
                            });

                            map.drawRoute({
                                origin: [latlng1.lat(), latlng1.lng()],
                                destination: [latlng2.lat(), latlng2.lng()],
                                travelMode: 'driving',
                                strokeColor: '#131540',
                                strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                                strokeWeight: 6
                            });
                            map.getRoutes({
                                origin: [latlng1.lat(), latlng1.lng()],
                                destination: [latlng2.lat(), latlng2.lng()],
                                callback: function (e) {
                                    var time = 0;
                                    var distance = 0;
                                    for (var i=0; i<e[0].legs.length; i++) {
                                        time += e[0].legs[i].duration.value;
                                        distance += e[0].legs[i].distance.value;
                                    }
                                    alert(time + " " + distance);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated fiddle shows drive time and distance for the first route returned based on the input text boxes. Will be easy to extend from here to add a search button and update the map.

Comment: Fiddle is broken because the `raw.github` include is read-only. Use rawgithub.com instead: `https://rawgithub.com/HPNeo/gmaps/master/gmaps.js`

Comment: @couzzi I could not reproduce it not working, but updated with your correction anyway. Possibly works differently when I am logged in? Edit: looks like it is not multi browser friendly - thanks for the heads up: https://rawgithub.com/

Comment: Possibly, but as a rule, you should never use `raw.github` includes. No too long ago they switched to read-only (nosniff) to act as a deterrent. rawgithub.com exists to undo that. There's a blurb explaining it here [http://rawgithub.com/](http://rawgithub.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only care about distance between point A. and point B., and not turn-by-turn directions—It should be as simple as taking the coordinates of your two points and calculating the distance.

#### Example - calculate the distance from the center of New York City to the center of Philadelphia

- [Fiddle for miles: http://jsfiddle.net/DXNzu/](http://jsfiddle.net/DXNzu/)
- [Fiddle for kilometers: http://jsfiddle.n.et/DXNzu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/DXNzu/1/)

### JS

```
function distanceFrom(points) {
    var lat1 = points.lat1;
    var radianLat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var lng1 = points.lng1;
    var radianLng1 = lng1 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var lat2 = points.lat2;
    var radianLat2 = lat2 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var lng2 = points.lng2;
    var radianLng2 = lng2 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var earth_radius = 3959; // or 6371 for kilometers
    var diffLat = (radianLat1 - radianLat2);
    var diffLng = (radianLng1 - radianLng2);
    var sinLat = Math.sin(diffLat / 2);
    var sinLng = Math.sin(diffLng / 2);
    var a = Math.pow(sinLat, 2.0) + Math.cos(radianLat1) * Math.cos(radianLat2) * Math.pow(sinLng, 2.0);
    var distance = earth_radius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt(a)));
    return distance.toFixed(3);
}

var distance = distanceFrom({
    // NYC
    'lat1': 40.713955826286046,
    'lng1': -74.00665283203125,
    // Philly
    'lat2': 39.952335,
    'lng2': -75.163789
});
```

The result is  `80.524` miles or `129.583` kilometers.

In the event that you want the user to be able to input city names, zip codes, etc. instead of coordinates,
you could use the GMaps library to geocode the addresses first.

---

Related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530404/geolocation-watchposition-distance-calculator/15530759#15530759)

Comment: He is asking for routing (which would be required to work out drive time).

Comment: @Matthew, indeed he is. My mistake. In which case I concede to your awesome answer. Hope you get the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the gebweb optimap tsp solver. It can also solve the travelsalesman problem. Link: http://www.gebweb.net/optimap/